# While (web services netbeans)

Tags: java, xml, web-services, netbeans

i have this method adn i have to remove all the orders from the same client. here is the .xml file from which i am removing

```
<encomendas>
   <encomenda cod="enc4" data="2016-04-23" cliente="cli5" status="pendente">
      <enc quant="3">9789722523288</enc>
      <enc quant="1">9789726656272</enc>
   </encomenda>
   <encomenda cod="enc5" data="2016-05-16" cliente="cli7" status="pendente">
      <enc quant="1">9789720043702</enc>
      <enc quant="1">9789724146348</enc>
      <enc quant="2">9789724121390</enc>
      <enc quant="1">9789720046451</enc>
   </encomenda>
   <encomenda cod="enc6" data="2016-04-23" cliente="cli5" status="pendente">
      <enc quant="3">9789722523288</enc>
      <enc quant="1">9789726656272</enc>
   </encomenda> 
</encomendas>
```

and here is the code that i made

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "removeorder2")
public String removeorder2(@WebParam(name = "cliente") String id) {
    URL u = this.getClass().getResource("orders.xml");
    Document doc = XMLJDomFunctions.lerDocumentoXML(u.getFile());
    Element encomendas = doc.getRootElement();
    for (int i = 0; i < encomendas.getChildren().size(); i++) {
        Element filho = encomendas.getChildren().get(i);
        if (filho.getAttribute("cliente").getValue().equals(id)) {
            encomendas.getChildren().remove(i);
            XMLJDomFunctions.escreverDocumentoParaFicheiro(doc, u.getFile());
            return "order removed";
        }

    }
    return "order doesnt exist";
}
```

but like this i am only removing one when i insert the client that i want remove.
For example if i insert cli5 it will remove the first cli5 that he finds. I have do a cicle while but i don't know how to, do I make an xpath counting how many clients i have or there are easy ways to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you return the method immediately when you remove something. You can take `return "order removed";` out of the for loop, and have something like a flag variable to check whether there's something removed.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "removeorder2")
public String removeorder2(@WebParam(name = "cliente") String id) {
    boolean check = false;
    URL u = this.getClass().getResource("orders.xml");
    Document doc = XMLJDomFunctions.lerDocumentoXML(u.getFile());
    Element encomendas = doc.getRootElement();
    for (int i = 0; i < encomendas.getChildren().size(); i++) {
        Element filho = encomendas.getChildren().get(i);
        if (filho.getAttribute("cliente").getValue().equals(id)) {
            encomendas.getChildren().remove(i);
            XMLJDomFunctions.escreverDocumentoParaFicheiro(doc, u.getFile());
            check = true;
        }

    }
    if (check) return "order removed";
    return "order doesnt exist";
}
```

One other thing is about the remove logic. Let say you remove an item at index 1, and so the next item will have index 1, right. But in the next interaction, you go the index 2, and the third item now is at index 1 will be skipped? So I guess you have to recheck the index of the next item and make sure you're not skipping anything.

Btw, what is the method `escreverDocumentoParaFicheiro`?

Comment: i don't think i understand your question...but it worked! thank you for your help.

Comment: the method  `escreverDocumentoParaFicheiro` is to change the file. for example in the file you have cli5 cli5 cli7 cli5 if you eliminate cli5 that method will write the changes in the file so it will only appear cli7.

Comment: Hmm you still need to recheck the index of the next loop. 

Let say you have 4 items, a, b, b, c and you want to remove all b item, right. Find the first b at index 1, remove it. 

So what happens: the index of the second b now is index 1. But because you already update the loop, so you will check index 2 and find c over there. Thus leaving the second b at index 1, not being removed.

Comment: i put an `i--;` after `check = true;` and it worked! if i leave it like that will it always work?

Comment: Yes for sure. One more thing, move the line `XMLJDomFunctions.escreverDocumentoParaFicheiro(doc, u.getFile());` to somewhere out of the loop. You don't want to write file every single loop do you? Just write it once, at the end of the code, or better only write it if something changed.

Comment: I did what you said, thank you so much for your help. :)